# How does BigQuery search through a cluster / partition?

Tags: google-bigquery

My colleague asked if it was possible to reverse the order of the data in a cluster. So it would look something like the following.
| Normal cluster | Reversed cluster |
|---|---|
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |

I said that I can remember reading that the data is searched through like a binary tree, so it doesn't really matter if it's reversed or not. But now I can't find anything that mentions how it actually searches through the cluster.

How does BigQuery actually search for a specific value in clusters / partitions?

Answer (score 0):

When you create a clustered table in BigQuery, the data is automatically organized based on the contents of one or more columns in the table’s schema. The columns that we specify are used to colocate related data. When you cluster a table using multiple columns, the order of columns we specify is important, as the order of the columns determines the sort order of the data.

When you create a partitioned table, data is stored in physical blocks, each of which holds one partition of data. A partitioned table maintains these properties across all operations that modify the data. You can typically split large tables into many smaller partitions using data ingestion time or `TIMESTAMP/DATE` column or an `INTEGER` column.

Comment: So can you reverse the order of the data in a cluster?

Comment: You can invert the columns, take this as an example

--clustering_fields= title, song